# @click detected twice in Vue3 Leaflet <l-map>

Tags: leaflet, vuejs3

I have added a function (addMarker) to be called when clicking on the map using the following:

```
<template>
  <l-map 
  style="height: 550px" 
  :zoom="zoom" 
  :center="center"
  @click="addMarker"
  >
    <l-control-layers position="topleft" :collapsed="false"></l-control-layers>
    <l-tile-layer
        v-for="tileProvider in tileProviders"
        :key="tileProvider.name"
        :name="tileProvider.name"
        :visible="tileProvider.visible"
        :url="tileProvider.url"
        :attribution="tileProvider.attribution"        
        layer-type="base"/>     
    <l-control position="topright" >
      <button @click="getUserLocation">
        Find my location
      </button>
    </l-control>
  </l-map>
</template>

data() {
 return { 
  methods: {
   addMarker(event) {       
    console.log(event.latlng)
   }
  }
 }
}
```

However, this is causing issues. Firstly, when clicking the map, the function "addMarker" is being called twice (see below):

[image]

Secondly, clicking on other elements such as `<l-control-layers>` or `<l-control>` is still detecting the map click.

Comment: for me pass the same i filter the market by  latlng with value

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug! The best solution is using an 'if' for checking that  if the click is triggered by map.

```
<script>
setup(){
    const addPoint = (event) => {
                if (event.latlng != undefined) {
                    /.....
                }
            };
     return {addPoint}

}
<script>
```